# Kendo Tabstrip Doesn't Load First Tab Properly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm currently using the new Q3 release of Kendo and am having an issue with the Kendo tabstrip control. I have a tabstrip that has 11 tabs and the third tab navigates out of the page to a different view. From this view when I navigate back (either with breadcrumbs or through the back button on the browser), I select the third tab and refresh it's content. However, after this reverse page navigation the content in the first tab doesn't show when I click on it; all I see is a grey background in the tab. When I inspect the control I can see all of the controls there with the correctly bound information. If I select the first tab when I navigate back to the page everything gets loaded correctly.

I have no idea what is wrong or how to fix this issue. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

--EDIT--
Below is how the tabstrip is set up.

```
<div class="" id="tabstrip">
<ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">
            <i class="green icon-info-sign bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_juryMaster_lbl_CandidateInfo            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-info-sign bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_juryMaster            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-question-sign bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_eQuestion            
    </li>
    <li>
            <i class="green icon-bell bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_Events            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-flag bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_Flags            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-file bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_DM            
    </li>
    <li>
            <i class="green icon-calendar bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_Scheduling
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-money bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_Financials            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-exchange bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_Merge            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-suitcase bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_NameHistory            
    </li>
    <li>            
            <i class="green icon-list-ul bigger-110"></i>
            @ResxStrings.PersonStrings.tab_heading_JudgesNotes            
    </li>

</ul>
<div><div id="candidateInfo"></div></div>
<!--BEGIN juryMaster CONTENT-->
<div id="juryMaster">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_JuryMaster.cshtml")           
</div>
<!-- /juryMaster -->

<!--BEGIN eQuestion CONTENT-->
<div id="eQuestion">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_eQuestion.cshtml")

</div>
<!-- /eQuestion -->

<!-- BEGIN Events CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_Events.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/Events-->

<!-- BEGIN Flags CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_Flags.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/Flags-->

<!-- BEGIN DM CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_DM.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/DM-->

<!-- BEGIN Scheduling CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_Scheduling.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/Scheduling-->

<!-- BEGIN Financials CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_Financials.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/Financials-->

<!-- BEGIN MergeUnMerge CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_MergeUnMerge.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/MergeUnMerge-->

<!-- BEGIN NameHistory CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_NameHistory.cshtml")
</div>
<!--/NameHistory-->

<!-- BEGIN JudgesNotes CONTENT-->
<div>
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/Partial_JudgesNotes.cshtml")
</div> 
<!--/JudgesNotes-->
```

and in the script:

```
        $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        select: onSelect,
        effects: "expand:vertical",
        activate: onActivate,
        animation: false
    });
```

The select method gets the first tab and selects/refreshes it, and the activate method just involves grid formatting on a separate tab. Below is the method being called when the first tab is selected

```
    function loadJurorSummary(jurorID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Person/getPersonSummary")',
        type: "GET",
        data: { id: jurorID },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#candidateInfo").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works fine on first load and navigation on the same page.

Comment: Can you provide some code showing the tab setup

Comment: sure thing I made the edit with code samples

Comment: Looks like you're using Razor--have you thought about implementing this using that API? Or even the *.aspx implementation?

Comment: Hi Todd, I'm pretty limited on how I can implement this functionality so I won't be able to use *.aspx. Using razor is definitely an option, but I don't see this issue being fixed just from changing to the RAZOR implementation. The thing is I don't remember if this was an issue before the kendo upgrade since I don't remember testing this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

From the [demo for ajax loaded content](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/ajax.html) it appears that you need to pass in your content urls as an array in the tabstrip declaration:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn"} },
        contentUrls: [
                    '../../content/web/tabstrip/ajax/ajaxContent1.html',
                    '../../content/web/tabstrip/ajax/ajaxContent2.html',
                    '../../content/web/tabstrip/ajax/ajaxContent3.html'
                ]
    });
});
```

When you go to dev tools (assuming you're using Chrome or IE) do you see any script errors in the console?

Comment: Hi Todd, I'm certain I have all dependencies and I don't have any HTTP 500 errors with reverse navigation. This is why I'm finding such a hard time to debug and fix since there aren't any script errors or console errors haha. The first tab has all of the controls ( I can see them in the inspector) but there is a grey overlay on the div. I tried changing the background of the div but that still doesn't make the controls show. I'll try this ajax loading but right now I'm using custom implementation where I select the tab and it calls a method in the appropriate partial to load the data.

Comment: Just as a continuation: so I would prefer to keep this custom implementation and avoid restructuring the tabstrip declaration with contentUrls if possible.

Comment: Strange. If I understand correctly, when you navigate back the ajax call are sending JSON that's binding to the control(s) on that first tab? Do you see any 404 errors with your Kendo-related assets (css)?

Comment: Yes that is correct. No 404 errors and no errors of any kind. I agree this is strange, I'm not sure if this is a bug with the new kendo version or not... I know it's not an issue with the specific content in the first tab. I changed tab contents and still get the same behavior on the first tab. It works correctly if I select the first tab on reverse navigation, but breaks whenever I select a different tab..